# How to share an USB device(scanner) over network (from Windows to Ubuntu)?

Tags: 10.04, software-recommendation, windows, usb, share

I have a special thing: I want to share my scanner over the network. The scanner is connected to a Windows 7 machine, but I want to use it from Ubuntu 10.04...

I found some methods:

- [USB over Network](http://www.usb-over-network.com/usbnet-solutions/remote.html) - it can handle
  **Linux > Windows**; and **Windows > Windows** it has **Windows** (and
  **Windows CE**) & **Linux** server, but it has only **Windows client**, their
  Linux client is coming soon - that's
  a drag :( - it is not free, but *what uses Windows, what is free?*
- [USBip](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/) - to Linux > Linux, it is free, and nice

I'm looking for the other way, what can handle **Windows > Linux** thing... I prefer free things, but that thing is maybe not free...

Comment: Try researching Samba solutions.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion, but what Samba solutions is available for sharing a scanner, not a printer... I know the printer is easy shareable(I already shared it), but that is a scanner(but it is a MFP - **HP psc 2175**)

Answer (score 1):

"If you want to share with another Linux or Unix system, SANE alone should work. If you want to share with a Windows client, you'll need a Windows SANE front-end, such as [SaneTwain](http://sanetwain.ozuzo.net)."

Source: http://fixunix.com/smb/62684-sharing-printers-scanner-samba.html